Concatenate pages of memory without copying the memory (by e.g. memcpy)
How to concatenate pages of memory without copying the memory (by eg.: memcpy()) ?
Take this example in which 3 regions of memory pages are allocated:
size_t GetStuff(char* Dest, size_t MaximumSize);

n1 = GetStuff(NULL, maximum*PAGE_SIZE);
char* p1 = VirtualAlloc(NULL, n1, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);    
GetStuff(p1, n1);

n2 = GetStuff(NULL, maximum*PAGE_SIZE);
char* p2 = VirtualAlloc(NULL, n2, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
GetStuff(p2, n2);

n3 = GetStuff(NULL, maximum*PAGE_SIZE);    
char* p3 = VirtualAlloc(NULL, n3, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
GetStuff(p3, n3);

It is possible to concatenate these 3 pages of memory into a contiguous address space, without destroying their contents, like this:
char* pAll = VirtualAlloc(NULL, n1+n2+n3, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
VirtualAlloc(pAll, n1+n2+n3, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
memcpy(pAll, p1, n1);
memcpy(pAll+n1, p2, n2);
memcpy(pAll+n1+n2, p3, n3);

...but is it possible without the memcpy() ? - by just remapping these 3 memory regions into consecutive virtual memory addresses, like it is possible to do in Windows kernel mode with MDLs and in Linux with mremap().

Why not originally allocate the 3x space pAll and then cut it up for p1, p2, p3 with simple pointer math?

Because the sizes of these allocations is not known ahead of time (but they are guaranteed to be a multiple of the PAGE SIZE) . These PAGE_SIZE allocations are only abstracted out of an algorithm as a Minimal Verifiable Example.

In Linux this is possible to do if the original pages are mapped from a file (which can be a memfd rather than on disk). Then you can alias the pages by creating another mapping of the same byte range from the file. Perhaps something similar is possible with Windows?

On the other hand, compiler generated code often doesn't do well with aliased pages like this. Compilers don't expect that a write to one address can change the value read from a different address. So you may have to use volatile liberally.

You can use MapViewOfFile on a file mapping (which could be a pagefile-backed mapping; i.e., just virtual memory) to place the mapping into memory wherever you like. Unfortunately, the granularity is 64KB, not PAGE_SIZE. An alternative is MapUserPhysicalPages which lets you operate at the page level.

@Raymond: Is MapUserPhysicalPages() limited to AWE ?  Is AWE present only in 32-bit processes ?

@GeorgeRobinson - this is work in 64bit processes of course too
